# List files of particular extension

Tags: file-format, ls

Ok this is strange. I am using this code,

```
ls *.prj
```

To list all the files with the .prj extension in the dir but I am getting this error,

> bash: /bin/ls: Argument list too long

I eventually wish to get the count of files and I was using,

> ls *.prj | wc -l

But even this command is giving the same error. Any idea where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nothing, there is a limit on the number of argument bash can deal with. Do

```
ls | grep '\.prj$' | wc -l
```

Comment: Yup that works great, that is what I wanted. Let this 15 min rule pass and I will select this as the right answer

Answer (score 11):

Use `find` command instead

```
 find . -name "*.prj"
```

You can also combine the commands with find

```
find . -name "*.prj" -exec COMMAND {} \;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: that would be correct if all the files in the directory were having only .prj extn, but I have files with same names but different extensions and your commands lists all of them

Comment: but by doing `ls *.prj` you are tyring to list the files with extn .prj right?

Comment: the answer is above

Comment: can we do this for multiple extensions too?

Answer (score 3):

[Parsing the output of `ls` is unreliable](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). It will probably work in your case, but `ls` mangles unprintable characters. Here is a fully reliable way of counting the files matching a certain extension. This shell snippet creates an array containing the file names, then prints the number of elements in the array.

```
shopt -s nullglob
a=(*.prj)
echo ${#a[@]}
```

Comment: ok I tried this and `echo` is giving me value 17 but the actual value is 90419, which is correctly calculated by the other two commands above

Comment: @Sam007 Sorry, that was an error in my command, I used zsh syntax that gives a different result in bash. `${#a}` in zsh calculates the length of the array, but in bash it gives the length of the first element, and you need `${#a[@]}` to get the number of elements.

Comment: Yup that is working

Comment: Even if there is not a file with that extension, it outputs 1.  And the list contains *prj