# Argument list too long when copying files

Tags: command-line, files

I just asked a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217742/list-files-of-particular-extension) related to how I can count the files of particular extension. Now I want to `cp` these files to a new `dir`.

I am trying,

```
cp *.prj ../prjshp/
```

and

```
cp * | grep '\.prj$' ../prjshp/
```

but they are giving the same error,

> bash: /bin/cp: Argument list too long

How do I copy them?

Comment: Related: [Does "argument list too long"
 restriction apply to shell builtins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47443380/does-argument-list-too-long-restriction-apply-to-shell-builtins)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

`cp *.prj ../prjshp/` is the right command, but you've hit a rare case where it runs into a size limitation. The second command you tried doesn't make any sense.

One method is to run `cp` on the files in chunks. The `find` command knows how to do this:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -name '*.prj' -exec mv -t ../prjshp {} +
```

- `find` traverses the current directory and the directories below it recursively.
- `-maxdepth 1` means to stop at a depth of 1, i.e. don't recurse into subdirectories.
- `-name '*.prj'` means to only act on the files whose name matches the specified pattern. Note the quotes around the pattern: it will be interpreted by the `find` command, not by the shell.
- `-exec … {} +` means to execute the specified command for all the files. It invokes the command multiple times if necessary, taking care not to exceed the command line limit.
- `mv -t ../prjshp` moves the specified files into `../prjshp`. The `-t` option is used here because of a limitation of the `find` command: the found files (symbolized by `{}`) are passed as the last argument of the command, you can't add the destination after it.

Another method is to use `rsync`.

```
rsync -r --include='*.prj' --exclude='*' . ../prjshp
```

- `rsync -r … . ../prjshp` copies the current directory into `../prjshp` recursively.
- `--include='*.prj' --exclude='*'` means to copy files matching `*.prj` and exclude everything else (including subdirectories, so `.prj` files in subdirectories won't be found).

Comment: rsync, by far the easiest solution here.

Comment: To be somewhat nitpicky, the second command `cp * | grep '\.prj$' ../prjshp/`  does not make any sense, but can be a syntactically valid, if `*` expands to list of files with the last one being a directory ( aka `cp SOURCE1 SOURCE2....DEST` ). The pipe does not make any sense, sure, but also remains syntactically valid as far as shell is concerned - it will `dup()` the file descriptors just fine, it's just that reader end of the pipe won't get any data because `cp` doesn't write any.

Comment: Both find and rsync produced the same argument list too long error for me. The for loop was the simplest workaround.

Comment: Indeed rsync is the way to do any mass copying, although I'm stumped at how far we have come with Linux and we have a silly flaw/bug like this and yes I would consider it a flaw/bug.

Answer (score 38):

This command copies the files one by one and will work even if there are too many of them for `*` to expand into a single `cp` command:

```bash
for i in *; do cp "$i" ../prjshp/; done
```

Comment: This works for me.

Comment: Simple and effective. I had a similar issue removing ~1/4 million jpegs I had extracted from a video for a project. This is the approach I used.

Comment: Thanks, this made my day! Works like a charm in Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS. I had a problem copying all files from a backup directory that had an immense amount of files in a single directory; even `rsync` threw the "Argument list too long when copying files"-error at me when I attempted to use that instead. It's ridiculous that we have to resort to these types of workarounds in simple Linux terminal commands in 2020 A.D.

Comment: Slow, though. I like that this is so simple, and it works for me, but in my case (very small files) it's moving about 3MB / second, whereas `cp -r` moves maybe 0.5GB / second.

Answer (score 10):

There's 3 key points to keep in mind when facing `Argument list too long` error:

- The length of command-line arguments is limited by `ARG_MAX` variable, which by [POSIX definition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/limits.h.html) is  "...[m]aximum length of argument to the **exec functions** including environment data" (emphasis added)". That is, when shell executes a non-built-it command, it has to call one of `exec()` to spawn that command's process, and that's where `ARG_MAX` comes into play. Additionally, the name or path to the command itself ( for example, `/bin/echo` ) plays a role.
- Shell built-in commands are executed by shell, which means the shell doesn't use `exec()` family of functions and therefore aren't affected by `ARG_MAX` variable.
- Certain commands, such as `xargs` and `find` are aware of `ARG_MAX` variable and repeatedly perform actions under that limit

From the points above and as shown in [Kusalananda's excellent answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/451548/85039) on related question, the `Argument list too long` can also occur when environment is big. So taking in consideration that each user's environment may vary, and the argument size in bytes is relevant, it's hard to come up with a single number of  files/arguments.

#### How to handle such error ?

The key thing is to focus not on the number of files, but focus on whether or not the command you're going to use involves `exec()` family of function and tangentially - the stack space.

**Use shell built-ins**

As discussed before, the shell built-ins are immune to `ARG_MAX` limit, that is things such as `for` loop, `while` loop, built-in `echo`, and built-in `printf` - all those will perform well enough.

```
for i in /path/to/dir/*; do cp "$i" /path/to/other/dir/; done
```

On [related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/451548/85039) about deleting files, there was a solution as such:

```
printf '%s\0' *.jpg | xargs -0 rm --
```

Note that this uses shell's built-in `printf`. If we're calling the external `printf`, that will involve `exec()`, hence will fail with large number of arguments:

```
$ /usr/bin/printf "%s\0" {1..7000000}> /dev/null
bash: /usr/bin/printf: Argument list too long
```

**bash arrays**

According to [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1698611/3701431) by jlliagre, `bash` doesn't impose limits on arrays, so building array of filenames and using slices per iteration of loop can be done as well, as shown in danjpreron's [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/678919/295286):

```
files=( /path/to/old_dir/*.prj )
for((I=0;I<${#files[*]};I+=1000)); do 
    cp -t /path/to/new_dir/ "${files[@]:I:1000}" 
done
```

This, however, has limitation of being bash-specific and non-POSIX.

**Increase stack space**

Sometimes you can see people suggest [increasing the stack space](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/45584/85039) with `ulimit -s <NUM>`; on Linux ARG_MAX value is 1/4th of stack space for each program,  which means increasing stack space proportionally increases space for arguments.

```
# getconf reports value in bytes, ulimit -s in kilobytes
$ getconf ARG_MAX
2097152
$ echo $((  $(getconf ARG_MAX)*4 ))
8388608
$ printf "%dK\n" $(ulimit -s) | numfmt --from=iec --to=none
8388608
# Increasing stack space results in increated ARG_MAX value
$ ulimit -s 16384
$ getconf ARG_MAX
4194304
```

According to [answer by Franck Dernoncourt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/245762/85039), which cites Linux Journal, 
one can also recompile Linux kernel with larger value for maximum memory pages for arguments, however, that's more work than necessary and opens potential for exploits as stated in the cited Linux Journal article.

**Avoid shell**

Another way, is to use `python` or `python3` which come by default with Ubuntu.  The python + [here-doc](https://askubuntu.com/a/678919/295286) example below, is something I personally used to copy a large directory of files somewhere in the range of 40,000 items:

```py
$ python <<EOF
> import shutil
> import os
> for f in os.listdir('.'):
>    if os.path.isfile(f):
>         shutil.copy(f,'./newdir/')
> EOF
```

For recursive traversals, you can use [os.walk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1698611/3701431).

#### See also:

- [What defines the maximum size for a command single argument?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/120642/85039)

Comment: Who doesn't enjoy recompiling the Linux kernel in their spare time?

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, the optimal tools for dealing with hordes of files are `find` and `xargs`. See `man find`. See `man xargs`. `find`, with its `-print0` switch, produces a `NUL`-separated list of filenames (filenames may contain any character execpt `NUL` or `/`) that `xargs` understands, using the `-0` switch. `xargs` then builds the longest command allowed (the most filenames, no half-filename at the end) and executes it. `xargs` repeats this until `find` supplies no more filenames. Run `xargs --show-limits </dev/null` to see the limits.

To solve your problem, (and after checking `man cp` to find `--target-directory=`):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.prj' -print0 | xargs -0 cp --target-directory=../prjshp/
```