# What's the difference between <<, <<< and < < in bash?

Tags: command-line, bash, redirect

What's the difference between `<<`, `<<<` and `< <` in bash?

Comment: At least in these Google-centric times, it's difficult to search for these symbol-based operators. Is there a search engine where you could plug in "<< <<< < <" and get anything useful?

Comment: @DanielGriscom There's [SymbolHound](http://symbolhound.com/).

Comment: @DanielGriscom Stack Exchange used to support searching symbols, but then something broke and no one ever fixed it.

Comment: It's already there (and has been for almost a year): [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/23408)

Comment: @muru classic stack exchange

Comment: @DanielGriscom I just googled `bash <<<` and this came up first. So looks like they improved something in the last 7 years ;)

Comment: @Jorn good to know.

Comment: @Dennis Seems like [SymbolHound](http://symbolhound.com/) is non operational now (atleast from where I am).

Comment: I know you left that comment nearly a decade ago now, but I came here from DuckDuckGo'ing "bash <<", so at least some search engines still work :) And I've anecdotally found that when punctuation is being ignored in my search query then putting it in "quote marks" gets me helpful results.

Answer (score 372, accepted):

**Here document**

`<<` is known as `here-document` structure. You let the program know what will be the ending text, and whenever that delimiter is seen, the program will read all the stuff you've given to the program as input and perform a task upon it.

Here's what I mean:

```
$ wc << EOF
> one two three
> four five
> EOF
 2  5 24
```

In this example we tell `wc` program to wait for `EOF` string, then type in five words, and then type in `EOF` to signal that we're done giving input. In effect, it's similar to running `wc` by itself, typing in words, then pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>

In bash these are implemented via temp files, usually in the form `/tmp/sh-thd.<random string>`, while in dash they are implemented as anonymous pipes. This can be observed via tracing system calls with `strace` command. Replace `bash` with `sh` to see how `/bin/sh` performs this redirection.

```
$ strace -e open,dup2,pipe,write -f bash -c 'cat <<EOF
> test
> EOF'
```

**Here string**

`<<<` is known as `here-string`. Instead of typing in text, you give a pre-made string of text to a program. For example, with such program as `bc` we can do `bc <<< 5*4` to just get output for that specific case, no need to run bc interactively. Think of it as the equivalent of `echo '5*4' | bc`.

Here-strings in bash are implemented via temporary files, usually  in the format `/tmp/sh-thd.<random string>`, which are later unlinked, thus making them occupy some memory space temporarily but not show up in the list of `/tmp` directory entries, and effectively exist as anonymous files, which may still be referenced via file descriptor by the shell itself, and that file descriptor being inherited by the command and later duplicated onto file descriptor 0 (stdin) via `dup2()` function. This can be observed via

```
$ ls -l /proc/self/fd/ <<< "TEST"
total 0
lr-x------ 1 user1 user1 64 Aug 20 13:43 0 -> /tmp/sh-thd.761Lj9 (deleted)
lrwx------ 1 user1 user1 64 Aug 20 13:43 1 -> /dev/pts/4
lrwx------ 1 user1 user1 64 Aug 20 13:43 2 -> /dev/pts/4
lr-x------ 1 user1 user1 64 Aug 20 13:43 3 -> /proc/10068/fd
```

And via tracing syscalls (output shortened for readability; notice how temp file is opened as fd 3, data written to it, then it is re-opened with `O_RDONLY` flag as fd 4 and later unlinked, then `dup2()` onto fd 0, which is inherited by `cat` later ):

```
$ strace -f -e open,read,write,dup2,unlink,execve bash -c 'cat <<< "TEST"'
execve("/bin/bash", ["bash", "-c", "cat <<< \"TEST\""], [/* 47 vars */]) = 0
...
strace: Process 10229 attached
[pid 10229] open("/tmp/sh-thd.uhpSrD", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 3
[pid 10229] write(3, "TEST", 4)         = 4
[pid 10229] write(3, "\n", 1)           = 1
[pid 10229] open("/tmp/sh-thd.uhpSrD", O_RDONLY) = 4
[pid 10229] unlink("/tmp/sh-thd.uhpSrD") = 0
[pid 10229] dup2(4, 0)                  = 0
[pid 10229] execve("/bin/cat", ["cat"], [/* 47 vars */]) = 0
...
[pid 10229] read(0, "TEST\n", 131072)   = 5
[pid 10229] write(1, "TEST\n", 5TEST
)       = 5
[pid 10229] read(0, "", 131072)         = 0
[pid 10229] +++ exited with 0 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=10229, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Opinion: potentially because here strings make use of temporary text files, it is the possible reason why here-strings always insert a trailing newline, since text file by [POSIX definition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/446241/85039) has to have lines that end in newline character.

**Process Substitution**

As [tldp.org](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) explains,

> Process substitution feeds the output of a process (or processes) into
> the stdin of another process.

So in effect this is similar to piping [stdout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) of one command to the other , e.g. `echo foobar barfoo | wc` . But notice: in the [bash manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/bash.1) you will see that it is denoted as `<(list)`. So basically you can redirect output of multiple (!) commands.

*Note:* technically when you say `< <` you aren't referring to one thing, but two redirection with single  `<` and process redirection of output from `<( . . .)`.

Now what happens if we do just process substitution?

```
$ echo <(echo bar)
/dev/fd/63
```

As you can see, the shell creates temporary file descriptor `/dev/fd/63` where the output goes (which according to [Gilles's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156088/85039), is an anonymous pipe). That means  `<` redirects that file descriptor as input into a command.

So very simple example would be to make process substitution of output from two echo commands into wc:

```
$ wc < <(echo bar;echo foo)
      2       2       8
```

So here we make shell create a file descriptor for all the output that happens in the parenthesis and redirect that as input to `wc` .As expected, wc receives that stream from two echo commands, which by itself would output two lines, each having a word, and appropriately we have 2 words, 2 lines, and 6 characters plus two newlines counted.

How is process substitution implemented ? We can find out using the trace below (output shortened for brevity)

```
$ strace -e clone,execve,pipe,dup2 -f bash -c 'cat <(/bin/true) <(/bin/false) <(/bin/echo)'
execve("/bin/bash", ["bash", "-c", "cat <(/bin/true) <(/bin/false) <"...], 0x7ffcb96004f8 /* 50 vars */) = 0
pipe([3, 4])                            = 0
dup2(3, 63)                             = 63
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f6c12569a10) = 8954
strace: Process 8954 attached
[pid  8953] pipe([3, 4])                = 0
[pid  8953] dup2(3, 62)                 = 62
[pid  8953] clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f6c12569a10) = 8955
strace: Process 8955 attached
[pid  8953] pipe([3, 4])                = 0
[pid  8953] dup2(3, 61)                 = 61
[pid  8953] clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f6c12569a10) = 8956
[pid  8953] execve("/bin/cat", ["cat", "/dev/fd/63", "/dev/fd/62", "/dev/fd/61"], 0x55ab7566e8f0 /* 50 vars */) = 0
```

The above trace on Ubuntu (which also implies on Linux in general) suggests that process substitution is implemented by repeatedly forking multiple subprocesses (so process 8953 forks multiple child processes 8954,8955,8956,etc). Then all these subprocesses communicate back via their stdout , but that is duplicated (that is copied) onto the stack of next available file descriptors starting at 63 downwards. Why start at 63 ? That may be a good question for the developers. It is known for a fact that [`bash` can use fd 255](https://askubuntu.com/a/866722/295286) for saving file descriptors for the "main" command/pipeline  when its streams are redirected.

*Side Note:* Process substitution may be referred to as a **bashism** (a command or structure usable in advanced shells like `bash`, but not specified by POSIX), but it was implemented in `ksh` before bash's existence as [ksh man page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36870/ksh-1.html) and [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/49952/85039) suggest.
Shells like `tcsh` and `mksh` however do not have process substitution. So how could we go around redirecting output of multiple commands into another command without process substitution? Grouping plus piping!

```
$ (echo foo;echo bar) | wc
      2       2       8
```

Effectively this is the same as above example, However, this is different under the hood from  process substitution, since we make stdout of the whole subshell and stdin of `wc` [linked with the pipe](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/). On the other hand, process substitution makes a command read a temporary file descriptor.

So if we can do grouping with piping, why do we need process substitution? Because sometimes we cannot use piping. Consider the example below - comparing outputs of two commands with `diff` (which needs two files, and in this case we are giving it two file descriptors)

```
diff <(ls /bin) <(ls /usr/bin)
```

Comment: `< <` is used when one is getting stdin from a _process substitution_. Such a command might look like: `cmd1 < <(cmd2)`.  For example, `wc < <(date)`

Comment: Good to know. By the way, on mksh that doesn't seem to work. Probably a bashism ?

Comment: Yes, process substitution is supported by [bash, zsh, and AT&T ksh{88,93} but not by pdksh/mksh.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution)

Comment: Then again, some would call `<<<` a bashism too.

Comment: `< <` *isn't a thing* by itself, in the case of process substitution it's just a `<` followed by something else that happens to start with `<`

Comment: @muru As far as I know, `<<<` was first implemented by the Unix port of Plan 9 rc shell then later adopted by zsh, bash and ksh93. I wouldn't then call it a bashism.

Comment: @jlliagre and process substitution was [first implemented by ksh](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/49952/70524). That's why I said "*some* would call..." Pedantry has its uses, this is not one of them.

Comment: @muru Sorry, I clearly misunderstood your previous comment. Neither of these features are indeed bashisms as they were first implemented elsewhere.

Comment: Serg, as my discussion with @jlliagre shows, neither process substitution nor here strings are bashisms. To say that they can only be used in bash is just plain false. Further, as jlliagre's answer shows, the point of process substitution is not feeding the output of multiple commands to something (for which commands groups are sufficient and standard), but for cases where you want to avoid pipes.

Comment: @muru noted and improved; added example where piping cannot be used

Comment: Another example of where piping cannot be used: `echo 'foo' | read; echo ${REPLY}` will _not_ return `foo`, because `read` is started in a sub-shell — piping starts a sub-shell. However, `read < <(echo 'foo'); echo ${REPLY}` correctly returns `foo`, because there is no sub-shell.

Comment: If you'd like to make the `strace` examples more readable and understandable use the `-y` flag too

Comment: Minor nit: I'm having a hard time understanding the meaning of, `Instead of typing in text, you give a pre-made string of text to a program` in the context of `<<<`. Fortunately, the last sentence in the same paragraph perfectly clarifies: "Think of [`bc <<< 5*4`] as the equivalent of `echo '5*4' | bc`."

Answer (score 49):

`< <` is a syntax error:

```
$ cat < <
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
```

`< <()` is [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) (`<()`) combined with redirection (`<`):

A contrived example:

```
$ wc -l < <(grep ntfs /etc/fstab)
4
$ wc -l <(grep ntfs /etc/fstab)
4 /dev/fd/63
```

With process substitution, the path to the file descriptor is used like a filename. In case you don't want to (or can't) use a filename directly, you combine process substitution with redirection.

To be clear, there is no `< <` operator.

Comment: i get by your answer that , < <() more useful than <() right?

Comment: @solfish `<()` gives a filename-like thing, so it's more generally useful - `< <()` is replacing the stdin where it might not be necessary. In `wc`, the latter happens to be more useful. It might be less useful elsewhere

Answer (score 21):

`< <` is a syntax error, you probably mean `command1 < <( command2 )` which is a simple input redirection followed by a process substitution and is very similar but not equivalent to :

```
command2 | command1
```

The difference assuming you are running `bash` is `command1` is run in a subshell in the second case while it is run in the current shell in the first one. That means variables set in `command1` would not be lost with the process substitution variant.

Comment: Isn't in the first the subshell? Don't we start a new subshell by `()`?

Comment: @adosar Sorry, I don't understand your question. Can you rephrase it clarifying which "first" you are referring to?

Comment: Apologize. I was referring to the subshell. Isn't a subshell created in the first case `< <(command2)` ?

Comment: @adosar Yes, `command2` is run in a subshell in the first example. What is run in the current shell is `command1`. No parenthesis are needed in the second example, the pipeline puts both `command1` and `command2` in subshells. That's bash default behavior.

Comment: I didn't know that pipeline puts both commands in subshells. Is there any reason that does this (other than affecting maybe variables in the current shell)?

Comment: @adosar The reason why the shell put all components of a pipeline in a subshell is it's easier to implement by shell developers. There is no potential conflicts between commands to solve. That's also the defaut POSIX behavior. ([POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_12): *Additionally, each command of a multi-command pipeline is in a subshell environment*)

Answer (score 17):

`< <` will give an syntax error. Proper use is as follows:

Explaining with the help of examples:

Example for `< <()`:

```
while read line;do
   echo $line
done< <(ls)
```

In the above example, the input to the while loop will come from the `ls` command which can be read line by line and `echo`ed in the loop.

`<()` is used for process substitution. More information and example for `<()` can be found at this link:

[Process substitution and pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17107/process-substitution-and-pipe)