# Concatenating md5 string

Tags: bash, encryption, md5sum

I have a little script file called `testing.sh` where I am asking user to enter his login and password. Then, the password is getting encrypted with `md5sum` command and the result is stored in a file `results.txt` in a form `login:md5password`. However, when I am viewing the `results.txt` file, I only get `login:`, the encrypted password isn't concatenated. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the `testing.sh` file:

```
#!bin/bash
read -p 'Your login: ' uservar
read -sp 'Your password: ' passvar

var=$passvar|md5sum
echo $uservar:$var > ~/Desktop/results.txt
```

`results.txt` file:

```
login:
```

Comment: By the way, `md5sum` isn't really meant for encryption. `md5sum` and similar utilities are hashes, i.e. they're meant to just go one way - get a hash sum out of them and used for verifying if data is correct or not, and not really meant to be "decrypted" (although, there's ways to get original string with weak hashes like `md5sum` and `sha1sum`, which was cracked last year). Just FYI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing `var` assignment in wrong way.

```
var=$passvar|md5sum
```

You're supposed to send `"$passvar"` to `md5sum`. It won't go through pipe `|` by itself, so you either need to use `echo`, or `printf`. That will output things to `stdout` stream. You can capture that into variable with command substitution `$(...)`. In other words, you should be doing:

```
var=$( echo "$passvar" | md5sum )
```

Also, please remember to quote the variables to preserve the integrity of data stored in them and prevent [word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting).

---

Other issues:

```
$ read -sp 'Your password:' passvar
Your password:$ var=$( echo "$passvar" | md5sum )
$ echo "$var"
2b00042f7481c7b056c4b410d28f33cf  -
```

Notice two things here: there's no newline after "Your password", so you might want to add `echo` after that command. Second, notice that `md5sum` outputs filename after the calculated md5 checksum, which in this case is `-` or `stdin` stream. You might want to consider getting rid of that part via any text processing utility that will let you cut away words, like `awk`:

```
var=$( echo "$passvar" | md5sum | awk '{print $1}')
```

Alternatively, you can just make use of `bash`'s read and here-string `<<<` (see [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/678915/295286) for more info on that operator) :

```
$ read var trash <<< $( echo "$passvar" | md5sum )
$ echo "$var"
2b00042f7481c7b056c4b410d28f33cf
```

Last but not least, your `#!` line is missing `/` before `bin` - it should be `#!/bin/bash`.

The complete script should be as so:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
read -p 'Your login: ' uservar
read -sp 'Your password: ' passvar
printf "\n"
read var trash <<< "$(printf "%s" "$passvar" | md5sum)"
printf "%s:%s" "$uservar" "$var" #> ~/results.txt
```

Note that I commented out redirection to file, just to see the output on the terminal for testing purpose. Here's how it works:

```
$ ./testing.sh 
Your login: johndoe
Your password: 
johndoe:912ec803b2ce49e4a541068d495ab570$
```

---

For future reference, you can add `set -x` after `#!/bin/bash` (given that you've properly defined the `#!` line, of course) to troubleshot the script and see what commands actually run and were errors might arise. Or just use [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) online tool.

Comment: @Rockasaurus Very well ! I'm glad I could help. Happy scripting!

Answer (score 1):

The following script also working for me.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n 'Your login:'
read uservar

echo -n 'Your password:'
read -s passvar

printf "\n"

encrpt=$(echo "$passvar" | md5sum | awk '{print $1;}')

echo "$uservar":"$encrpt" > /home/bond/result.txt
```

**Output**

```
bond@hp-pc:~$ ./test.sh 
Your login:bond
Your password:
bond@hp-pc:~$ cat result.txt 
bond:22c291f0335f869c154d8081854d9119
```

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Thanks for the comment, i have edited my answer as per the comment.