# Pasting in terminal with indentation

Tags: command-line, python, clipboard

I am pasting a python code in Ubuntu Terminal. However, the code contains for loops for which indentation is necessary. Is there a way to paste the code maintaining indentation. I remember there is a command like paste"some character" which directly pastes with indentation. But I cant find it online.

Can somebody suggest a way or remind me of the command?

Comment: I am aware of that possibility. But I am trying to analyze some data for which I need to run the code snippet by snippet because its easier to comprehend the data, in that way (at least for me)

Comment: Can you give an example of the code you are pasting and also tell us which program is running in terminal when you are pasting it?

Comment: It is basically an analysis of some numbers and some graphs related to them. I am using the basic Ubuntu Terminal

Comment: @mathisbetter We need an example of the code so we can try it ourselves. As for the terminal, we need to know what shell you're running in it, like `python`, `python3`, `ipython`, `pypy`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're better off pasting code to python interpreter. In the shell, however, you can start [here-doc](https://askubuntu.com/a/678919/295286) redirection with `python <<EOF`, paste code, and close it with `EOF`. Like so:

```
$ python3 <<EOF
> for i in range(5):
>     print(i)
> EOF
0
1
2
3
4
```

Of course, make sure you're using proper Python version and your code syntax matches that.

---

If you wanna get creative, install `xclip` package to access clipboard contents programmatically ( installation is done via `sudo apt-get install xclip`) and create the following function in your `.bashrc`, then source it:

```
pyfromclip(){ python3 < <(xclip -o -sel clip); }
```

This function uses process substitution `< <()` feature of `bash`, and redirects output of `xclip`, which releases clipboard contents to its `stdout` stream, into python's `stdin` stream.

```
$ cat ./hello_world.py 


d = { "Hello": 1, "World": 2 }

for key,value in d.items():
    print(key,value)
$ xclip -sel clip ./hello_world.py 
$ # We copied into clipboard, so now let's run it
$ pyfromclip 
Hello 1
World 2
```