# How to execute SQL statement from command line?

Tags: command-line, postgresql, sql

I'm a longtime GUI user trying to switch to command line, and I'm not sure how to execute an SQL statement from the Ubuntu command line. I'm using postgres.  I can use `\c` to connect to the database and `\d` to see the tables in it. I can also see the headers with `\d dbname` (where `dbname` is the name of the database).  What I can't do is see the actual data.

I tried  `SELECT * FROM dbname;` and I got a "syntax error at or near dbname".  I Tried it without the semi colon, and just got a new command line.  How do I see my data?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/app-psql.html)

Comment: You don't `SELECT` from a database; you `SELECT` from a table - I usually start with `use dbname;` then `show tables;`

Comment: Right. Actually that's a type-o.  I meant from table.

Comment: This might help someone https://stackoverflow.com/a/56042488/4593057

Answer (score 12):

Edit: OP's actual problem apparently is table name that entirely consists of digits. According to [SQL-92 standard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15917064/3701431) table names cannot start with a digit, but otherwise can contain digits. For such case, one simply needs to wrap the name in double or single quotes as in `SELECT * FROM "12345";`

Essentially, what you need is the [`psql` command](http://postgresguide.com/utilities/psql.html) - the command-line interpreter for Postgres, which comes by default with Postgres installation on Ubuntu. Running `psql -U username databasename` will allow you to connect to that, and execute SQL queries via that command-line interpreter. If you're asking about running commands while in `bash` shell, you should be using `psql` command with `-c` flag. Something along the lines of

```
psql -U username -d database.db -c "SELECT * FROM some_table"
```

For multiline queries you can use [heredoc](https://askubuntu.com/a/678919/295286):

```
$ psql -U admin_serg hello_world <<EOF
> SELECT * FROM foobar;
> EOF                  

 foo |     bar     
-----+-------------
   1 | Hello World
(1 row)
```

Of course, if you haven't created a particular user with `postgres` , you might want to do that, or just log in as `psql` user first, `sudo su postgres`.

As for syntax error, you probably tried to enter an SQL query directly into the command-line ( in your case, that'd be probably `bash` shell ). That's not how this works - `bash` doesn't understand SQL, only its own syntax, hence why `psql` command-line interpreter exists, just like for other databases (`sqlite3` for instance) or there's GUI tools for that(like `pgAdmin` for postgres or `sqlitebrowser` for sqlite3).

See also:

- [PostgreSQL - query from bash script as database user 'postgres'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18223665/3701431)
- [How to create user for a db in postgresql?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10861260/3701431)

Comment: Sorry we answered at the exact same time. Had I seen yours I wouldn't have posted mine. You might need to install postgres SQL to keep track of all your great answers :)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Hehe, I already have both `Postgres` and `Sqlite3` installed.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix You answer is good, so no worries there. Besides, gives a different perspective. It's always good to have variety of answers.

Comment: Thanks Sergiy.  I am entering from the psql command line as a superuser. I'm still not getting a return of the data, just the next command line.

Comment: @j450n Can you provide the exact command you're trying ? Any errors reported ?

Comment: Sure.  From my user command, I use sudo -u postgres psql and enter my sudo password.  I then get the prompt as "postgres=#" for my command line structure.  From there I use \c dbname to enter the database, which then gives me the "dbname=#" prompt.  I then do a \d to get a list of tables to find the table I want.  I then hit "Q" to go back to the dbname=# prompt. Then I try "SELECT * FROM  tablename;" and I get an error that says:ERROR: syntax error at or near "tablename" LINE 1: SELECT * FROM tablename.  I try it without the semi colon and I just get the next command prompt

Comment: @j450n Are you also entering the square brackets as well ? Because they're not supposed to be there. As for `;` it's a statement terminator, so if you don't provide it, `psql` will expect a longer, multi-line statement, which in the end you have to terminate with `;` anyway and only then hit Enter.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy No. I'm not using brackets. I just don't know how to enter the code into here to make it with the gray background.  

Well, when I terminate the statement with a semi colon it gives me the error, so I'm not sure what to do

Comment: @j450n Well something is definitely not typed right, if it says syntax error. How about just `SELECT 2+2;` ?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy That returns 4 in a column with 1 row

Comment: crypto_test=# SELECT 2+2; 
 ?column? 
----------
        4
(1 row)

Comment: crypto_test=# SELECT * FROM 425147;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "425147"
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM 425147;
                      ^

Comment: A "\d" gives:         List of relations
 Schema |  Name  | Type  |  Owner   
--------+--------+-------+----------
 public | 425147 | table | postgres , so that is the right table name

Comment: @j450n Very odd. Try to put the name in single quotes, perhaps the query treats it as integer, while it needs a string

Comment: @j450s Yes, apparently by SQL standard, table names can't have names that start with digits, but it's fine if you enclose it in quotes

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy  Thanks for your help! That did it! It needed double quotes though. Mark this as solved.  Thanks again!

Comment: @j450n Very well.   Just go ahead and click the grey checkmark next to the answer. That marks an answer as accepted, which indicates question being solved as well

Answer (score 1):

You can issue commands from the terminal, but you can get an [open source package](https://www.pgcli.com/) with tab completion, colours, etc:

[image]

---

Using the generic program [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/tutorial-accessdb.html) use:

```
$ psql mydb
```

If you leave off the database name then it will default to your user account name. You already discovered this scheme in the previous section.

In psql, you will be greeted with the following message:

```
Welcome to psql 8.3.23, the PostgreSQL interactive terminal.

Type:  \copyright for distribution terms
       \h for help with SQL commands
       \? for help with psql commands
       \g or terminate with semicolon to execute query
       \q to quit

mydb=>
```

The last line printed out by psql is the prompt, and it indicates that psql is listening to you and that you can type SQL queries into a work space maintained by psql. Try out these commands:

```
mydb=> SELECT version();
                            version
----------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 8.3.23 on i586-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC 2.96
(1 row)

mydb=> SELECT current_date;
    date
------------
 2002-08-31
(1 row)

mydb=> SELECT 2 + 2;
 ?column?
----------
        4
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error message because you forgot to include the Schema in you `SELECT * FROM dbname;` query.

You shouldn't be using \d, you should use \dt with the Schema name (not DB name). for example `\dt "MySchema".*`

**Here's how to connect and see your DB, Schemas, and Tables:**

*) Type "\?" for help

*) Type "\conninfo" to see which user you are connected as.

*) Type "\l" to see the list of Databases.

[image]

*) Connect to a database by "\c ", for example "\c GeneDB1"

[image]

You should see the key prompt change to the new DB, like so: [image]

*) Now that you're in a given DB, you want to know the Schemas for that DB. The best command to do this is "\dn".

[image]

Other commands that also work (but not as good) are "select schema_name from information_schema.schemata;" and "select nspname from pg_catalog.pg_namespace;":

[image]

-) Now that you have the Schemas, you want to know the tables in those Schemas. For that, you can use the "dt" command. For example "\dt "GeneSchema1".*"

[image]

*) Now you can do your queries. For example:

[image]

*) Here is what the above DB, Schema, and Tables look like in pgAdmin:

[image]