# Meaning of "exec tail -n +3 $0" line in 40_custom file

Tags: grub2

I am trying to understand the grub config files. So, during this process I came across with file */etc/grub.d/40_custom*. My file contains the following lines:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
menuentry "Windows 10" --class windows --class os {
insmod part_msdos
savedefault
insmod ntfs
insmod ntldr
set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
ntldr ($root)/bootmgr
}
```

as my system is dual boot and apparently this is the boot loader for windows 10.

My question though is this part `exec tail -n +3 $0`.
If I am deciphering it correctly this just means print the last lines starting from the 3rd line (`+3`) of the file `$0`. `$0` of course in this case is the actual file */etc/grub.d/40_custom*.

So, why do we use this command in *40_custom* file? As I get it the output would be the same if ιt was omitted altogether. The only different I might think of is the 1st line which identifies the interpreter:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

But then again it is executed since `exec tail -n +3 $0` follows it. So, is this just a (useless) convention?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The trick is what `exec` does:

```
$ help exec
exec: exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments ...]] [redirection ...]
    Replace the shell with the given command.

    Execute COMMAND, replacing this shell with the specified program.
    ARGUMENTS become the arguments to COMMAND.  If COMMAND is not specified,
    any redirections take effect in the current shell.
```

This means it will replace the shell with whatever is given to `exec`, in this case `tail`. Here's an example of it in action:

```
$ cat ~/foo.sh
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 "$0"
echo foo

$ ./foo.sh
echo foo
```

So the `echo` command isn't executed since we have changed the shell and are using `tail` instead. If we remove the `exec tail`:

```
$ cat ~/foo.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo foo
$ ./foo.sh
foo
```

So, this is a neat trick that lets you write a script whose only job is to output its own contents. Presumably, whatever calls `40_custom` expects its contents as output. Of course, this begs the question of why not just running `tail -n +3 /etc/grub.d/40_custom` directly.

I am guessing the answer is because `grub` [uses its own scripting language](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Shell_002dlike-scripting) and this makes it need this workaround.

Comment: Nice answer! But what if we'll write `#!/bin/tail -n +2` as a shellbang? Will it print rest of the file?

Comment: @val try it and see :) Turns out it doesn't work perfectly as a shebang, the `-n +2` seems to be interpreted as `-n 2` and only the last two lines are printed. That's probably worth its own question though.

Comment: @val ...shebang behavior is a lot less standardized and portable than you may expect. See the "interpretation of the command arguments" section of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)#Portability

Comment: @val That works in Linux if you remove the space between the `n` and the `+`. In Linux at least, after the executable path and a space, the following characters are treated as a single argument. So with the space, tail sees it and probably decides to remove whatever invalid prefix `-n`'s argument has (in this case, a space and a `+`) until it gets to the number. However, like Charles Duffy said, the current way they did this is probably more portable to other Unices.

Comment: Why can't this just use a heredoc? Or a cat hashbang?

Comment: @fluffy well, for one thing those would return the entire file, but we only want the later lines. But for more details, please ask the authors of Grub.

Comment: @fluffy They *can* use here doc. See the link from Fedora documentation in my answer. They use exactly `cat <<EOF ...EOF` there

Answer (score 9):

The directory `/etc/grub.d/` contains many executables (typically shell scripts, but any other executable type is also possible). Whenever `grub-mkconfig` gets executed (e.g. if you run `update-grub`, but also when you install an updated kernel package, which usually has a *post-install hook* that tells the package manager to update `grub.cfg`), they are all executed in alphabetical order. Their outputs all get concatenated, and end up in the file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, with neat section headers that show which part comes from which `/etc/grub.d/` file.

This one particular file `40_custom` is designed to allow you to easily add entries/lines into `grub.cfg` by simply typing/pasting them into this file. Other scripts in the same directory do more complex tasks like looking for kernels or non-linux operating systems and creating menu entries for them.

In order to allow `grub-mkconfig` to treat all those files in the same way (execute and take the output), `40_custom` is a script and uses this `exec tail -n +3 $0` mechanism to output its contents (minus the "header"). If it weren't an executable, `update-grub` would need a special hard-coded exception to take this file's literal text content instead of executing it like all the others. But then what if you (or the makers of another linux distribution) want to give this file a different name? Or what if you didn't know about the exception and created a shell script named `40_custom`?

You can read more about `grub-mkconfig` and `/etc/grub.d/*` in the [GNU GRUB Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Simple-configuration.html#Simple-configuration) (although it talks mostly about options you can set in `/etc/default/grub`), and there should also be a file `/etc/grub.d/README` that states that these files get executed to form `grub.cfg`.

Comment: While terdon's answer explains how the line works, this one gives a more plausible design reason as for why GRUB does things this way.

Comment: Great answer. To your point about special exceptions - a "simpler" exception could have been having two directories e.g. `/etc/grub.d/exec` for exectuable files/scripts, and `/etc/grub.d/static` for plain text files, or some other indicator to distinguish these. However, this was the design decision that they went with.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR**: it's a trick to simplify adding new entries to the file

The whole point is described in one of the [Ubuntu's Wiki pages on grub](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup#Scripts:_.2Fetc.2Fgrub.d.2F):

> 3. Only executable files generate output to grub.cfg during execution of update-grub.

Output of scripts in `/etc/grub.d/` becomes the contents of `grub.cfg` file.

Now, [what does `exec` do ?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/296838/85039) It can either re-wire output for entire script or if a command is provided - the mentioned command overtakes and replaces the script process. What was once shell script with PID 1234 now is `tail` command with PID 1234.

Now you already know that `tail -n +3 $0` prints everything after the 3rd line in the script itself. So why do we need to do this ? If grub only cares about the output we could just as well do

```
cat <<EOF
    menuentry {
    ...
    }
EOF
```

In fact, you will find `cat <<EOF` example in [Fedora documentation](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/21/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sec-GRUB_2_Password_Protection.html), albeit for a different purpose. The whole point is in the comments - ease of use for the users:

```
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.
```

With `exec` trick, you don't have to know what does `cat <<EOF` do (spoiler, that's called [here-doc](https://askubuntu.com/a/678919/295286)), nor you have to remember to add the `EOF` on the last line. Just add menuentry to the file and be done with it. Plus, if you're scripting adding a menuentry, you can simply append via `>>` in shell to this file.

#### See also:

- [What logic does the command “exec tail -n +3 $0” from grub2 config have?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/420205/85039)

Comment: But why not have grub read the files directly? Do you have any idea why they chose to make them executable instead? It would be much simpler to have them as  simple text files which are read by whatever process generates the menu, but instead they chose to make them executable and added this (neat) but complex workaround. Is it because grub has its own scripting language as I posit in my answer?

Comment: @terdon  I don't think this has to do anything with the grub language itself. You wouldn't need `#!/bin/sh` in that case.  I suspect this is simply historical reason (carried over from [PUPA](http://www.nongnu.org/pupa/) codebase ) and a design decision inspired by SysV type of scripting.

Comment: @terdon This actually inspired a question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/492966/85039