# How to properly launch tmux on terminal startup?

Tags: command-line, bash, shortcut-keys, bashrc, tmux

I've used this snippet to launch tmux when the terminal is launched:

```
# TMUX startup
if command -v tmux>/dev/null; then
 [[ ! $TERM =~ screen ]] && [ -z $TMUX ] && exec tmux
fi
```

But with this I can't exit tmux without the terminal screen being closed too.

I've tried:

`Ctrl + b :detach`

`exit`

And looking for the PID and killing it. All those methods close the terminal too.

How should I configure tmux to start when launching the terminal but still being able to close it without the terminal closing? Any tips are appreciated!

Comment: I've just tried and replacing the snipped I used with just `tmux` works, but I get a: `sessions should be nested with care, unset $TMUX to force`. I've also tried leaving the snipped I used as it is and adding a `tmux` at the end of the `~/.bashrc` but then detaching still exits the terminal.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is the `exec` command. As explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1107671/85695), `exec` will replace the current shell with whatever you tell it execute. So you don't have a shell that is running `tmux`, you just have `tmux` and therefore exiting it will also exit the terminal.

Just remove the `exec` and it should work as expected:

```
if command -v tmux>/dev/null; then
 [[ ! $TERM =~ screen ]] && [ -z $TMUX ] && tmux
fi
```