# Bash saying that file doenst exist

Tags: server, bash

I'm trying to run this bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /ftp/slake/FiveM/cfx-server
[ -d cache ] || mkdir cache

exec FXServer $SERVER_ARGS $*
```

but it says that FXServer doesn't exist

[image: img_FXServer]

I'm new to linux so this might be a pretty dumb fails

Comment: Try `exec ./FXServer $SERVER_ARGS $*` and/or `exec /ftp/slake/FiveM/cfx-server/FXServer $SERVER_ARGS $*`.

Comment: `mkdir -p cache` is short for `[ -d ... ] || ...`

Answer (score 2):

When you run an executable by name, such as `FXServer`, your shell will look in all of the directories in the `$PATH` variable and try to find an executable with that name in one of them. It will then execute the first one it finds. Since `/ftp/slake/FiveM/cfx-server` is not in your `$PATH`, the only way this would work is if you had the current directory (`.`) in your `$PATH` and it looks like you don't. The simple solution is to just use the full path to the executable instead of just calling it by name:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /ftp/slake/FiveM/cfx-server
[ -d cache ] || mkdir cache

./FXServer $SERVER_ARGS $*
```

`./` means "the current directory" so that will execute the file called `FXServer` that is in the current directory. I removed the `exec` since that isn't needed and does [something very specific](https://askubuntu.com/a/1107671/85695).

A better version, assuming that this command needs to be run in the `/ftp/slake/FiveM/cfx-server`, would be add a test and exit if for some reason we can't change to the right directory (for instance if it doesn't exist). Also, you should [always quote your variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/22222) and you [almost certainly want `$@` and not `$*`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/94200/22222):

```
#!/bin/bash

if cd /ftp/slake/FiveM/cfx-server; then
    [ -d cache ] || mkdir cache
    ./FXServer "$SERVER_ARGS" "$@"
else
    echo "Failed to change directory to /ftp/slake/FiveM/cfx-server" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```