# How to concatenate two command in shell

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, dash-shell

I used to have this command to count how many times I have click with a mouse, the command is `xev | grep "ButtonPress"`.

my colleague modify the command so that it return:

```
ButtonPress 0
ButtonPress 1
ButtonPress 2
ButtonPress 3
```

and so on... Unfortunately he's no longer contactable so I can't reach him anymore.

I recall the involvement of `i++` and something like that, how to reproduce the command?

Comment: Do you mean `xev | grep -c "ButtonPress"`, showing the number of clicks on exit?

Comment: It shows `ButtonPress` + number everytime I click on white box pop up window, sorry I'm a novice...

Comment: dessert, your command worked but it only return the number when I exit `xev`. How to make it return live value ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The fact that there's `i++` suggests there was either `bash` or `ksh` shell in use,potentially `awk` or `perl` as well. In either case, we can use [process substitution](https://askubuntu.com/a/678919/295286) `<(...)` to feed output of `xev` to counting loop (although simple pipeline `xev | while...` could work just fine).

**text processing tools**:

Portably and for fewer key strokes we can use `awk` :

```
$ xev | awk '/ButtonPress/{print "ButtonPress",i++}'
ButtonPress 0
ButtonPress 1
ButtonPress 2
ButtonPress 3
```

`perl` version:

```
$ xev | perl -ne '/ButtonPress/ && printf("ButtonPress:%d\n",++$i)'
ButtonPress:1
ButtonPress:2
ButtonPress:3
```

**Shells**:

Here's what works in `bash`:

```
$ i=0; while IFS= read -r line; do [[ $line =~ ButtonPress ]] && { ((i++)); printf 'ButtonPress: %d\n' "$i";} ;done < <(xev)
ButtonPress: 1
ButtonPress: 2
ButtonPress: 3
```

In case you don't want spammy output of many lines, we can use `printf` to send control code to clear previous line and output only the running count (that is you'd only see integer value change on the line):

```
$ i=0; while IFS= read -r line; do [[ $line =~ ButtonPress ]] && { ((i++)); printf "\r%b" "\033[2K"; printf 'ButtonPress: %d' "$i";} ;done < <(xev)
```

Portably in POSIX shell:

```
$ xev | ( i=0; while IFS= read -r l; do case "$l" in  *ButtonPress*) i=$((i+1)) && printf 'ButtonPress:%d\n' "$i";;  esac ;done)
ButtonPress:1
ButtonPress:2
ButtonPress:3
```

**basic utils**:

For simple, quick, and dirty way we can hack this via `cat -n` with line count being printed on the left instead of right:

```
$ xev | grep --line-buffered 'ButtonPress' | cat -n
     1  ButtonPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
     2  ButtonPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
     3  ButtonPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
```

Comment: I tried your first command that has awk in it, it works but there's a bit of lag when the output return

Comment: However, your second and third command works perfectly, thanks a lot Sergiy

Comment: @JackieNelson  A bit of lag might suggest buffering, which may be related to another `awk` version in use. Recent Ubuntu uses `gawk` and before 16.04 default was `mawk` IIRC.  Regardless, glad I could help :)

Comment: Can you make so that the number start from one on `perl` version ? Not zero

Comment: @JackieNelson Yep, already changed that

Comment: I prefer a shorter version, so the update is helpful. Thanks ! By the way I don't see any difference with Perl command, so how do you make it start from one ? Just curious

Comment: @JackieNelson Difference is `$i++` in original and `++$i` in changed command. `$i++` is post increment - increment variable after assigning value to variable. `++$i` is pre-increment - increment variable first then assign to variable. This type of semantic is used most notably in C language and many others. Python has it too, but it's a bit more involved there :)

Comment: The same works in `awk` and `bash` as well: `xev | awk '/ButtonP/{print $1,++i}'` and `i=0; while IFS= read -r line; do [[ $line =~ ButtonPress ]] && { printf '%s %d\n' "${line%% *}" "$((++i))";} ;done < <(xev)`