# here strings versus input redirection

Tags: command-line, bash, redirect

The following example is taken from William Shott's *The Linux command line*. It is a shell script which gathers user info from the /etc/passwd file. The specific user for which this is done is read from stdin.

My question is about the "here string" used in line 7. Just for kicks, I tried using the redirection operator instead, but it did not work. Why?

PS: I have some background in C++ so I expected the string `file_info` to act as a stringstream.

```
     1  #!/bin/bash

     2  # read-ifs: read fields from a file

     3  FILE=/etc/passwd

     4  read -p "Enter a username > " user_name

     5  file_info="$(grep "^$user_name:" $FILE)"

     6  if [ -n "$file_info" ]; then
     7       IFS=":" read user pw uid gid name home shell <<< "$file_info"
     8       echo "User = '$user'"
     9       echo "UID = '$uid'"
    10       echo "GID = '$gid'"
    11       echo "Full Name = '$name'"
    12       echo "Home Dir. = '$home'"
    13       echo "Shell = '$shell'"

    14  else
    15      echo "No such user '$user_name'" >&2
    16      exit 1
    17  fi
```

Comment: What exactly did you try? The operators `>`,`>>`,`<` work on *streams* not variables, however you could use a process substitution to stream the contents of the variable ex. `IFS=":" read user pw uid gid name home shell < <(printf '%s' "$file_info")`

Comment: @steeldriver this is kind of the answer I was looking for. Can you elaborate though on this: `< <(printf '%s' "$file_info")`

Comment: Highly relevant https://askubuntu.com/q/678915/295286  There's also explanation of how herestrings work and how they are implemented at C level

Answer (score 0):

If you do something like

```
grep "^$user_name:" $FILE | IFS=":" read user pw uid gid name home shell
echo "User = '$user'"
```

the right side of the pipeline (the `read` command) is run in its own subshell process and the variables it sets are gone when it ends so `echo` just displays empty strings.

But you can do something like

```
grep "^$user_name:" $FILE | ( IFS=":" read user pw uid gid name home shell
    echo "User = '$user'" )
```

In this case the whole `(` ... `)` part is run in the same subshell and the variables are available for the `echo` call.