# Deleting many files results in "argument list too long"

Tags: command-line, bash, files, filesystem, rm

I have 280 thousand photos to delete in a folder, but some videos to keep.
In the folder, I gave the command: `#rm *.jpg`, but I get "argument list too long". When I create an argument to delete some of the photos, it works on a smaller set, like this: # rm 104-*.jpg.

How can I efficiently delete all the JPEG files in a directory without getting the message "Argument list too long"?

`#rm -f *.jpg` gives the same message.

[image]

Opening the folder in Caja uses too much memory and crashes. I am using [Ubuntu MATE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_MATE).

Comment: I got it down to 69K photos but rm *.jpg still says argument list too long

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A typical way to handle the “argument list too long” error is via the `find` command:

```
find  -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -name "*.jpg" -delete
```

Comment: This is a slow way to do what I already did, prior to steeldriver's answer. N-*.jpg extends from 0 to 198 or something like that. I thought about just writing a for loop to increment N in rm *N-N-N.jpg.  but thought there had to be a single efficient command to do such an operation.

Comment: @j0h As far as  the `104-*.jpg` part goes, I apologize for that, I thought that's a pattern for all the images. But this is a single command, which doesn't call anything external. Compared to steeldriver's command - two commands which also are slowed down by a pipe ( which implies buffering ) - I don't see how this single command is slow.

Comment: ah it might not be, as a single command, just the pattern match. Im tempted to let the same issue happen again just to test the solutions.

Comment: @j0h  I guess we're on the same topic then :) I'm working on an answer that should generate enough arguments that will get below or above the threshold to cause `Argument list too long` error intentionally. I might post a link once I figure this out.

Comment: Im thinking that around 10,000 items is the area that generates that error.

Comment: @j0h Actually, it's not related to number of items at all. It's the total size in bytes of the names that get passed to the command.

Comment: @j0h I posted an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1049726/295286). Also, please read the linked [Kusalananda's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/451548/85039) as well. Basically, it's difficult to estimate exact number of files.

Comment: find: warning: you have specified the -mindepth option after a non-option argument -type, but options are not positional (-mindepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments

Comment: @j0h The -mindepth has to come before -type. I'll edit shortly

Answer (score 8):

You can use `xargs`:

```
printf '%s\0' *.jpg | xargs -0 rm --
```

In `bash`, the `printf` command is a built-in and is not subject to the same argument length limitations.

Comment: Alternatively, using `./*.jpg` instead of relying on `--`. Makes it more portable

Comment: This command failed in a later attempt,  with : sudo: unable to execute /usr/bin/printf: Argument list too long
.... I think it may have succeeded previously, because i had been actively removing items.  prior to using the command. Sergiy's answer worked, without any file removal, so my answer has changed.

Comment: @j0h this answer works when `printf` is a bash shell builtin command; if you run it with `sudo` then (as you can see from the error message), `sudo` will invoke the external `/usr/bin/printf` - which is subject to the same argument length restrictions as any other command.