# How to merge many files together?

Tags: cat, merge

I have around 58,000 txt files that have the prefix `ppdb-` in a directory. I want to merge all of them into one file.
 Wgen I try to merge them using `cat ppdb-* >> out.txt` it gives me an error saying "-bash: /usr/bin/cat: Argument list too long".
Is there a way to merge all the files together efficiently?

Comment: Have a look at [Cannot merge files using cat ; Argument list too long](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167137/cannot-merge-files-using-cat)

Comment: This answer is covered by this similar question with the same bash error: https://askubuntu.com/a/949552/167115

Comment: _Is there a way to merge all the files together efficiently?_ Your question is not a duplicate of the link a give. Maybe there is a way of doing the concatenation more efficiently (the two answers use `cat`).

Answer (score 2):

Read `man find xargs` and do something like: (UNTESTED, remove `echo` when your tests succeed)

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name 'ppdb-*' -print0 |\
  xargs -0 -r echo cat >out.txt
```